# Iframe is not working. Struggling to execute script tags in Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am working with iframe tag for displaying ads.

I am using below code for it -

```
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
```

JS -

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('abc');

var doc = iframe.contentDocument ? iframe.contentDocument :(iframe.contentWindow ? iframe.contentWindow.document : iframe.document)

doc.open();

doc.write('<scr'+'ipt src="http://ib.adnxs.com/ttj?id=5506238&cb=${CACHEBUSTER}"></scr' + 'ipt>');

doc.close();
```

I tried it on normal HTML page and body gets blank in inner document of Iframe,
but same code I execute in codepen it get executed, and body filled with executed script.

I needed solution or alternate solution to make it work.

[image: Codepen result]

[image: Codepen Inspect]

[image: Local inspect]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try oldskool

[DEMO](http://plungjan.name/SO/iframe/)

```
<iframe name="iframe" src="emptypage.html"></iframe>
```

JS -

```
window.onload=function() {   
  var iframe = window.frames['iframe'];
  var doc = iframe.document;
  doc.write('<scr'+'ipt src="http://ib.adnxs.com/ttj?id=5506238&cb=${CACHEBUSTER}"></scr' + 'ipt>');
  doc.close();
}
```

Here is what I see now I add the script to another iframe raw and turn off ad blocking so it seems to work.

[image]

Comment: No luck. Console error - Uncaught TypeError: window.frames is not a function

Comment: Console error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

Comment: Try with an empty html page as src

Comment: Nothing response. it's valid tag. you can test your side. I am also editing que. with snapshots.

Comment: I see. It has to load first. I now get a security errror

Comment: I appreciate if you help me asap as I have production deployment tomorrow. and I am struggling very much.

Comment: will you able to execute it?

Comment: Yes. If I turn off adblocking

Comment: Ok Now I am also getting "securityError: Blocked a frame with origin 'null' from accessing a frame with origin 'null'. Protocols, domains, and ports must watch.". How do you tackle this security error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87691/discussion-between-rockstar-and-mplungjan).

Comment: I am away from keyboard

Comment: Turn off add blocking if you have it

Comment: I don't have any ad blocking. Can you share full page code to me?

Comment: I did. View source of my demo page

Comment: I copy past your source code exactly as it is. and I attached snap of output in question.

Comment: Do you HAVE an emptypage.html

Comment: Then I have no idea. Works in chrome in OS X

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I am also working in OSX chrome :). anyways any alternate solution for it?

Comment: No - my page works for me, does my page work for you?

Comment: yes you demo page working here. is it local path file problem?

Comment: Possibly. Hard to tell

Comment: have to test with local path?

Comment: Hey buddy, it get resloved :) . It's not working on local, but I deployed it on AWS mine and yours both code working. :) Thanks Very much as you given me a lead for this.