# JavaScript within <script> tags are not being executed in an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am building a simple online HTML IDE where students can type HTML into a codemirror editor and then when a button is clicked, the HTML is placed in an iframe to render the page.

My code in question:

```
function runit() { 
   var prog = myCodeMirror.getValue(); 
   var mypre = document.getElementById("output");
   mypre.contentDocument.body.outerHTML = prog; 
 
}
```

`prog` is the html from the editor, `mypre` is the iframe.

All html placed within `<body>` tags is correctly executed in the iframe.
All css code placed within `<style>` tags is correctly executed in the iframe.
However, any javascript placed within `<script>` tags is not executed in the iframe.

How can I get `<script>` tag contents to be correctly executed in the iframe?

Comment: Do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32164904/iframe-is-not-working-struggling-to-execute-script-tags-in-iframe) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651856/iframe-problems-script-src-not-loaded-at-all) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:

```js
const runit = () => document.getElementById("output").srcdoc = myCodeMirror.getValue();
```

We use the property `srcdoc` to change the content in the iframe as HTML

Comment: I recommend u using `let` instead of `var` and if the variable is not used two or more times you don't need to declare it and just use its value instead :)